# Jomsocial transfer from one server to another

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

I am trying to transfer my website with jomsocial from one server to another.
www.iremember.gr

Previous server steps:
Backup all the files from public_html folder.
Backup the DB from php my admin.

New server steps:
Install joomla, entered the prefix in DB of the previous DB prefix.
Deleted all files from public html and extract the backup from the previous server.
Export the DB from the previous server, to the new one.
Changed the configuration.php file with the new user/dbname/password.

Now when i try to enter the new server at this IP address
93.174.121.23/~niremco/

and i login ok.
It loads the main page
but when i try to enter a profile i get a 404 Error.

Although when i try to see the profile

http://93.174.121.23/~niremco/index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid=109
i can see it.
But not from the correct link that i had in the previous server
http://93.174.121.23/~niremco/team-iremember/profile

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: For Joomla related questions, it's better to use the [**Joomla Stack Exchange**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/) site, which is dedicated for Joomla. Now for your issues I am posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't copied the `.htaccess` file from the old website, you will need to copy it from the old Joomla website to the new one. This typically happens because the `.htaccess` file is considered to be a hidden file and as such does not get copied over automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, installing a clean Joomla first is totally unnecessary. As for why you are getting the 404 error pages, this is because you probably have URL rewrite enabled in global configuration, while there is not a proper .htaccess file sitting in your new server.

With proper I mean either no .htaccess at all, or one that was setup for your old hosting. I rather tend to think the second.

To test that your moved correctly your site, disable url rewrite from global configuration.

If you would want to test with url rewrites enabled, then I would suggest to edit the hosts file in your computer and point your domain to the ip address of the new server.

[**Google Search: How to edit my hosts file**](https://www.google.gr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how%20to%20edit%20my%20hosts%20file&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9U46VtSjHoPOcorHn9gN) - choose the resource for your OS.